Next.js Authentication Issue: Page Redirects to Login After 2-3 Seconds
I'm trying to build a new project with a Laravel backend and a Next.js frontend. I'm having issues with authentication. The login and register functions work without any problems, but when I try to authenticate a user with the authHook method, the page is visible for 2-3 seconds and then it forwards to the login page. How can I prevent this? I would like to protect all admin routes.

Repository for the example project 
const ExamplePage = () => {
    const { logout, user } = useAuth({ middleware: 'auth' })

    return (
        <>
            <p>{user?.name}</p>

            <button onClick={logout}>Sign out</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default ExamplePage

I've tried to validate cookies through getServerSideProps, but I couldn't make it work. Additionally, I would prefer not to write getServerSideProps for each page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
